# Xcode 6.2 to 6.4 update failed

Tags: xcode, mac-app-store

I waited for about 8 hours to finish my 2.6 GB download to update from Xcode 6.2 to 6.4. After waiting it says it is installed. Opening Xcode it prompted me to install additional files and I accepted it. Once the installation was finished, it still says that my version is 6.2. After restarting my Mac Mini it still says that my Xcode version is 6.2. I checked App store, and Xcode still wants to update to 6.4. Whereas my "Updates installed in the Last 30 Days" tab it indicates that I was done downloading the 6.4 version.

How can I update my Xcode 6.2 to 6.4?

Comment: If you are starting Xcode via the Dock icon, are you certain it's running `/Applications/Xcode.app` and not another version from somewhere else?

Comment: Apparantly it is still running try to quit it via dock, still 6.2

Comment: anyway to reopen my downloaded installer?

Comment: What happens if you go to *Finder* and start `/Applications/Xcode.app` directly?

Comment: still it says that my version is 6.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try to reinstall Xcode . For me it has works.